# How to put limit in Matlab programming

Tags: matlab

so i want to generate an eqution like theta= asind(x), then i make a program like this:

```
x=0.5:5
theta=asind(x)
if x>1
theta = out of range
otherwise x=<1
end
fprintf('theta')
```

but it gives an error: 
xrdError: File: xrd.m Line: 4 Column: 17
Unexpected MATLAB expression.

please help me

Comment: What is the output of the program supposed to be? At the moment your code is not a valid Matlab program.

Comment: if x>1, the theta values will display 'out of range', if x=<1 then theta will give some values

Comment: Where will 'out of range' be displayed? Will you get one 'out of range' message for each value of `x` that is out of range? Where will the valid values be displayed? Can you explicitly write out what you think this program should output?

Comment: Are you trying to assign the *string* `out of range` to `theta`? If so, you should put it between single quotes (`'out of range'`).

Comment: since x ranges from 0.5-5, then all values from x>1 will have out of range values, for example at x=0.5, theta = asind(0.5) =30, at x = 2, theta =asind(2)= out of range, i want an output in array form where (x,theta) = (0.5:5, theta(x))

Comment: please provide a valid syntax thanks

Comment: I gave you an answer, but I think you would be a lot better off spending some time reading about basic Matlab syntax before you look at it (or copy-paste it into your homework solutions).

Comment: How about `nan`? This is what matlab usually uses when a value cannot ve defined for some reason. Eg `inf-inf` `0/0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that you wanted the elements of `theta` to say "out of range" when the corresponding value of `x` is out of range, and otherwise to display the inverse sine of `x`.

This is a little odd in Matlab, because data in Matlab tends to be either arrays of numbers, or arrays of characters, but not a mixture of numbers and characters.

There *is* a way to mix numbers and characters by using what is called a *cell array*. A cell array can be created like this

```
cell1 = {};
cell2 = cell(5, 1);
```

and you assign and access the elements like this

```
cell1{1} = 'Hello';
cell1{2} = 7;
disp(cell{1})
```

So the program that (I think) you want to write would look something like

```
x = (0.5 : 5)';
theta = cell(size(x));

for i = 1:length(x)
    if x(i) < -1 || x(i) > 1
        theta{i} = 'Out of range';
    else
        theta{i} = asind(x(i));
    end
end

x, theta
```

which outputs

```
x =

0.5000
1.5000
2.5000
3.5000
4.5000


theta = 

[30.0000]
'Out of range'
'Out of range'
'Out of range'
'Out of range'
```

However, you should probably reconsider what it is you want your program to do, because a cell array is not a particularly easy data type to work with in Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

A sensible thing to do is to set values which are invalid or missing to `NaN` (not a number). This can easily be done without a loop:

```
x=0.5:0.1:5;  % changed spacing so there is more than one valid x
theta=asind(x);
theta(x>1)=NaN;
plot(x,theta); % will plot only the valid values
```